# What the best way to import assets in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a project with React JS, that contains lots of assets. And actually, I'm wondering what is the best way to import assets between these two methods : 
- Creating a **JSON file** that contains all informations, with their assets paths (eg. `mySuperImg: "../assets/img/myImage.jpg"` then using the path for my image tags)
- Importing all assets directly **in** the component (or using the Context API, perhaps?) (eg. `import {myImage} from "../assets/myImage.jpg"` then using the img tag with that path `<img src={myImage} alt="My Image"/>`)

My questions : **What the best way to import assets** ? Is there a **speed difference** between these two methods ?

Thanks! Take care!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on you. Whichever way you feel comfortable, you should go for it. Generally, I import the assets in the corresponding file, but the other way can also be used. Instead of `json`, you could use `js` approach as well, similar to how we export actions, for eg,

```
export const ADD_PROJECT = "add_project";
export const FETCH_PROJECTS = "fetch_projects";
```

You could use something like,

```
export const IMAGE = require("the location to your image");
```

To answer if it would take more time, I don't think that there would be any performance issue, as we use a similar approach for the actions most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

it's best to keep the images in assets and use them in your source, if you work with the JSON file then you have to keep track of both of them and it will mess up as you say you have a lot of assets.